# Cannot find module '@nrwl/webpack/package.json'

Tags: nrwl-nx

Followed the nx dev tutorial TO THE LETTER :-)

https://nx.dev/react-tutorial

When I get to the "npx nx build admin" or "npx nx serve admin" steps I get an error:

Unable to resolve @nrwl/webpack:webpack

- for build

Unable to resolve @nrwl/webpack:dev-server

- for serve

I can fix the issue by adding "@nrwl/webpack": "^15.5.2" to devDependencies in package.json (and running npm install)

I assume this is a correct fix? Meanwhile, is the tutorial broken?

Expected tutorial to work without additional steps

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in V 15.5.2!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in V 15.5.2!

When I repeat the tutorial steps using V 15.4.5 (npx create-nx-workspace@15.4.5) the problem goes away.

Bug reported to nrwl team.

Just in case, this helps solve a problem for other developers...

Images are also broken in V 15.5.2 (and 15.5.3)! Basically images DO NOT DISPLAY...

```
import siteLogo from "./assets/images/modules/logo.png";
<img
            src={siteLogo}
            width="137px"
            height="47px"
            alt="Yamaha | Revs Your Heart"
          />
```

Reverting to 15.4.5 also fixes this issue!